# Unable to open react native app (error : none of these file exist node_modules\@stripe\stripe-react-native/src/hooks/)

Tags: android, react-native, stripe-payments

I am unable to open react-native app, build is getting failed after 91% Execution when I uninstalled tipsi-stripe and installed @stripe/stripe-react-native it started to give an error while executing app, Below error is showing while Executing :

**(error : none of these file exist node_modules@stripe\stripe-react-native/src/hooks/...)**

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to delete the `node_modules` folder, as well as the `yarn.lock` (or `package-lock.json`) and run a clean build again.

The `tipsi-stripe` is quite different from `stripe-react-native`, you can follow this [migration guide](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/blob/master/docs/tipsi-stripe-migration-guide.md) to make your code work with the new library.